# What is the meaning of each suffix in var AMPL

Tags: ampl

For AMPL, there is a list of possible suffix for variable, such as `_var.ub` which is the variable's upper bound.

I got a list of possible suffixes related to `_var`, and I want to know meanings of them.

`Possible suffix values for _var.suffix:
        astatus   current   defeqn   derstage
        down      dual      init     init0
        int       lb        lb0      lb1
        lb2       lrc       lslack   no
        rc        relax     slack    sno
        sstatus   stage     status   ub
        ub0       ub1       ub2      up
        urc       uslack    val`

such as `stage` means what?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the suffixes are described on the [BUILT-IN SUFFIXES](http://www.ampl.com/NEW/suffbuiltin.html) page. The `stage` suffix, which is not documented there, is used in stochastic programming extensions of AMPL to specify the stage of a variable. It is described in [Overview of and Update on ASL, the AMPL/Solver Interface Library](http://www.ampl.com/MEETINGS/TALKS/2010_11_Austin_TC40.pdf).